# Coupon System - Show adjusted price on next page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website with a cart and checkout page.
I don't know much about coding but I'm trying to implement by myself a coupon system on cart page.
It's working fine on cart page but I would like to show the results also on the next page which is my checkout page.

The result is a reduced price after coupon applied. It's on part 3 of my script. I don't know how to convert this result to a variable or other thing that I can put and read on the next page (checkout page). Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot

```
<!-- COUPON SYSTEM PART 1 - VARIABLES/QUERIES TO FIND COUPON CODE/AMOUNT ON DATABASE -->
<?php
 global $wpdb;
$coupon_code =  $wpdb->get_var("SELECT `code` FROM `wno_coupon` WHERE post_id = '$car_id'");
$coupon_amount =  $wpdb->get_var("SELECT `amount` FROM `wno_coupon` WHERE post_id = '$car_id'");
?>


<!-- COUPON SYSTEM PART 2 - CHECK IF USER INSERTED A COUPON VALID OR NOT  -->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['coupon-code'])){
if ($_POST['coupon-code'] == $coupon_code) { 
    echo "<script>alert('COUPON IS VALID')</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('COUPON IS NOT VALID')</script>";
}
}
?>

<form method="post" name="coupon_system" id="coupon_system">
                        <div class="apply-coupon">
                            <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-md-4">

                                <input type="text" name="coupon-code" id="coupon-code" value="" placeholder="Type here" class="form-control" style="text-transform: uppercase;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn_full">APPLY COUPON</button></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>


<!-- COUPON SYSTEM PART 3 - IF COUPON IS VALID THEN REDUCE THE PRICE AND SHOW THE NEW TOTAL PRICE   -->

<?php $total_price = $cart->get_field( $uid, 'total_price' ); if ($_POST['coupon-code'] == $coupon_code) { echo ct_price( $total_price - $coupon_amount );}
                                else if( ! empty( $total_price ) ) {echo ct_price($total_price );}?>
```

Comment: use the sessions

Comment: I tried to use sessions but nothing appears on checkout page.

I put this on cart page:

session_start();
$_SESSION['coupon'] = $_POST['coupon-code'];

and this on checkout page:

<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['coupon']; 
?>

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: thanks I got it. I just rewrote my .htaccess and now sessions are working